# Artist Colony - General extraction error

Tags: artist-colony

I just downloaded artist colony and installed it. When I tried to open the game, it says `General extraction error location es1`. How do I fix this?

Comment: FYI to those unfamiliar with this game: A fast Google search brings up Big Fish games, so this might be something along the lines of a Flash-esque game or similar.

Comment: @fbueckert - this is a casual simulation game. A bit more complicated than a flash game - think along the lines of Diner Dash or some such thing.

Comment: You can also try using "Compatibility Mode" (aka "XP Compatibility Mode") if you have it installed in your version of Windows 7 (you have this is you have at least Professional).

Answer (score 2):

This error refers to a few different problems. Some games from Big Fish Games and Gamehouse aren't able to work with Windows 7, and that might be the case here.

However, after doing some searching, it has been suggested that you try uninstalling your current version of Java and installing an older version (update 7 has been suggested in a few places).

If that doesn't work, it likely means that the game isn't compatible with your copy of windows 7 - a lot of older games, especially casual ones like this, weren't built to support newer operating systems - they are built for WinVista or older, and in many cases, haven't handled the switch to Win7 well.

Comment: I got windows 8 and the game worked perfectly before on another pc that is running windows 7

Comment: Then it might be Win8 that is the problem - considering it hasn't even seen a commercial release yet, expecting games to support it is a little much.

Comment: got the game installed on an external drive and it worked on windows 8 but when i want to install it on my pc it gave the error.